# How to display imageview inside cardview in a layout?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, drawable

I will make 6 cardviews that have an imageview in them. My code was successfully run on Android Nougat (api 25), but when I run on Android Kitkat (api 21), the imageview does not appear.

[image: cardview]

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardWJ"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
                    android:layout_rowWeight="1"
                    android:layout_columnWeight="1"
                    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="16dp"
                    app:cardCornerRadius="8dp"
                    app:cardElevation="8dp">

                    <LinearLayout
                        android:layout_width="match_parent"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|center_vertical"
                        android:layout_margin="5dp"
                        android:orientation="vertical">

                        <ImageView
                            android:layout_width="match_parent"
                            android:layout_height="80dp"
                            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:src="@drawable/icon_news" />

                        <TextView
                            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                            android:layout_gravity="center"
                            android:gravity="center_horizontal"
                            android:text="Warta"
                            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                            android:textSize="12sp"
                            android:textStyle="bold" />
                    </LinearLayout>
                </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Comment: Change your height and width to wrap_content.

Answer (score 0):

Your height and width of cardview are very small you need to change this.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
                    android:id="@+id/cardWJ"
                    android:layout_width="10dp"
                    android:layout_height="10dp"
```

to either:

```
               android:layout_height="wrap_content"
               android:layout_width="wrap_content"
```

or

```
              android:layout_width="80dp"
              android:layout_height="80dp"
```

depends upon your choice.Hope this will help you.

Answer (score 0):

First your card width and height should be wrap content not 
10dp, 10dp respectively. Your image is bigger than your cardview

Follow this link for more clarity 
https://www.dev2qa.com/android-cardview-with-image-and-text-example/